# Replacing template function foo(T*) by foo(T)

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, method-signature

In my code, I have a function:

```
template<typename T>
void foo (T*); // make sure that 'foo()' is passed only pointers
```

Now in new implementation, I am passing also a smart pointer (something like `shared_ptr<>`. So I have changed the signature of the function to,

```
template<typename T>
void foo (T);  // pointers or smart-pointers
```

The code shall work fine. However, is there any side effect I am missing ?

Comment: Those aren't template functions...

Answer (score 1):

You could use enable_if to only allow pointers or instances of shared_ptr to compile if you want. That way you can get back the compile-time checking you had before (though, presumably, your functions implementation would do that as well).

Comment: Note that this mechanism would fail for any type of smart pointer that is unknown to you. So the extensibility is somewhat limited.

Comment: Unless you were to create an is_pointer_type trait... Damn, there isn't one in Boost - it says to create your own! Lazy Boost :-(

Answer (score 0):

void foo(T) is pass-by-copy.
T& (pass by reference) would be more efficient if sizeof(T) is non-small.

Comment: ...but would be totally useless for the case where `T` is just a pointer. And most smart pointers aren't going to hold vast amounts of data outside the pointer. (Depending on the smart pointer type, it may hold nothing, and all the extra info would be stored alongside the pointed-to object.) And if you're going to do this, use `const T&` or else you might end up with some interesting side effects.